# Summing values of 2D array on indices

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, rowsum

I need to extend [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310766/summing-values-of-numpy-array-based-on-indices-in-other-array?rq=1), which sums values of an array based on indices from a second array.  Let `A` be the result array, `B` be the index array, and `C` the array to be summed over.  Then `A[i] = sum` over `C` such that `index(B) == i`.

Instead, my setup is

```
N = 5
M = 2

A = np.zeros((M,N))
B = np.random.randint(M, size=N) # contains indices for A
C = np.random.rand(N,N)
```

I need  `A[i,j] = sum_{k in 0...N} C[j,k]` such that `C[k] == i` , i.e. a rowsum conditional on the indices of B matching i.  Is there an efficient way to do this?  For my application N is around 10,000 and M is around 20.  This operation is called for every iteration in a minimization problem... my current looping method is terribly slow.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I follow the role of B here.  Could you edit to include the loop equivalent?

Comment: Oh, wait.  Is your `C[k] == i` supposed to be `B[k] == i`?

Comment: Bah!  Sorry, C[k] is supposed to be B[k]!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following @DSM's comment, I'm assuming your `C[k] == i` supposed to be `B[k] == i`.  If that's the case, does your loop version look something like this?

### Nested Loop Version

```
import numpy as np

N = 5
M = 2

A = np.zeros((M,N))
B = np.random.randint(M, size=N) # contains indices for A
C = np.random.rand(N,N)

for i in range(M):
    for j in range(N):
        for k in range(N):
            if B[k] == i:
                A[i,j] += C[j,k]
```

---

There's more than one way to vectorize this problem.  I'm going to show my thought process below, but there are more efficient ways to do it (e.g. @DSM's version that recognizes the matrix multiplication inherent in the problem).

For the sake of explanation, here's a walk-through of one approach.

---

### Vectorizing the Inner Loop

Let's start by re-writing the  inner `k` loop:

```
for i in range(M):
    for j in range(N):
        A[i,j] = C[j, B == i].sum()
```

It might be easier to think of this as `C[j][B == i].sum()`.  We're just selecting `j`<sup>th</sup> row of `C`, selecting only the elements in that row where `B` is equal to `i`, and summing them.

---

### Vectorizing the Outer-most Loop

Next let's break down the outer `i` loop. Now we're going to get to the point where readability will start to suffer, unfortunately...

```
i = np.arange(M)[:,np.newaxis]
mask = (B == i).astype(int)
for j in range(N):
    A[:,j] = (C[j] * mask).sum(axis=-1)
```

There are a couple different tricks here. In this case, we're iterating over the columns of `A`. Each column of `A` is the sum of a subset of the corresponding row of `C`. The subset of the row of `C` is determined by where `B` is equal to the row index `i`.

To get around iterating through `i`, we're making a 2D array where `B == i` by adding a new axis to i. (Have a look at the documentation for [numpy broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) if you're confused by this.) In other words:

```
B:
    array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0])

i: 
    array([[0],
           [1]])

B == i:
    array([[False, False, False, False,  True],
           [ True,  True,  True,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

What we want is to take two (`M`) filtered sums of `C[j]`, one for each row in `B == i`. This will give us a two-element vector corresponding to the `j`<sup>th</sup> column in `A`.

We can't do this by indexing `C` directly because the result won't maintain it's shape, as each row may have a different number of elements.  We'll get around this by multiplying the `B == i` mask by the current row of `C`, resulting in zeros where `B == i` is `False`, and the value in the current row of `C` where it's true.

To do this, we need to turn the boolean array `B == i` into integers:

```
mask = (B == i).astype(int):
    array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
           [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

So when we multiply it by the current row of `C`:

```
C[j]:
    array([ 0.19844887,  0.44858679,  0.35370919,  0.84074259,  0.74513377])

C[j] * mask:
    array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.74513377],
           [ 0.19844887,  0.44858679,  0.35370919,  0.84074259,  0.        ]])
```

Then we can sum over each row to get the current column of `A` (This will be broadcast to a column when it's assigned to `A[:,j]`):

```
(C[j] * mask).sum(axis=-1):
    array([ 0.74513377,  1.84148744])
```

---

### Fully Vectorized Version

Finally, breaking down the last loop, we can apply the exact same principle to add a third dimension for the loop over `j`:

```
i = np.arange(M)[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]
mask = (B == i).astype(int)
A = (C * mask).sum(axis=-1)
```

---

### @DSM's vectorized version

As @DSM suggested, you could also do:

```
A = (B == np.arange(M)[:,np.newaxis]).dot(C.T)
```

This is by far the fastest solution for most sizes of `M` and `N`, and arguably the most elegant (much more elegant than my solutions, anyway).

Let's break it down a bit.

The `B == np.arange(M)[:,np.newaxis]` is exactly equivalent to `B == i` in the "Vectorizing the Outer-most Loop" section above.

The key is in recognizing that all of the `j` and `k` loops are equivalent to matrix multiplication.  `dot` will cast the boolean `B == i` array to the same dtype as `C` behind-the-scenes, so we don't need to worry about explicitly casting it to a different type.

After that, we're just performing matrix multiplication on the transpose of `C` (a 5x5 array) and the "mask" 0 and 1 array above, yielding a 2x5 array.

`dot` will take advantage of any optimized BLAS libraries you have installed (e.g. `ATLAS`, `MKL`), so it's *very* fast.

---

### Timings

For small `M`'s and `N`'s, the differences are less apparent (~6x between looping and DSM's version):

```
M, N = 2, 5

%timeit loops(B,C,M)
10000 loops, best of 3: 83 us per loop

%timeit k_vectorized(B,C,M)
10000 loops, best of 3: 106 us per loop

%timeit vectorized(B,C,M)
10000 loops, best of 3: 23.7 us per loop

%timeit askewchan(B,C,M)
10000 loops, best of 3: 42.7 us per loop

%timeit einsum(B,C,M)
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.2 us per loop

%timeit dsm(B,C,M)
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.9 us per loop
```

However, once `M` and `N` start to grow, the difference becomes very significant (~600x) (note the units!):

```
M, N = 50, 20

%timeit loops(B,C,M)
10 loops, best of 3: 50.3 ms per loop

%timeit k_vectorized(B,C,M)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.5 ms per loop

%timeit ik_vectorized(B,C,M)
1000 loops, best of 3: 963 us per loop

%timeit vectorized(B,C,M)
1000 loops, best of 3: 247 us per loop

%timeit askewchan(B,C,M)
1000 loops, best of 3: 493 us per loop

%timeit einsum(B,C,M)
10000 loops, best of 3: 134 us per loop

%timeit dsm(B,C,M)
10000 loops, best of 3: 80.2 us per loop
```

Comment: @DSM - I can verify that it gives the same result, but you're absolutely right. It shouldn't be equivalent.  I need to think a bit more about it.

Comment: Well, I'm an idiot.. somehow I managed to remove the `axis=-1` and replace it with `axis=1` in your code, so it's not surprising that I couldn't reproduce anything.  Your version *does* match my `(B == np.arange(M)[:,None]).dot(C.T)` and `np.einsum('ij,kj->ik', B == np.arange(M)[:,None], C)`, and I should probably stop thinking today..

Comment: @DSM - For whatever it's worth, my original post had exactly that mistake (1 vs -1).  It I edited it in the first few minutes, so it doesn't show up as an edit, but your `axis=1` may have actually come from copy-pasting my initial answer. :) (And thanks for the `einsum` hint!)

Comment: @DSM - You should post those as an answer. Recognizing the inherent matrix multiplication makes the problem quite elegant (and much faster)!

Comment: @JoeKington: that would be work, and I'm lazy. :^)  Plus, I think pedagogical answers are more use both to the OP and to future searchers, and yours covers the matter nicely.

Comment: Very nice, @Joe.  Your timings should use `N >> M` though, since OP's case is `N ~ 10,000` and `M ~ 20`

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming @DSM found your typo, and you want:

```
A[i,j] = sum_{k in 0...N} C[j,k] where B[k] == i
```

Then you can loop over `i in range(M)` since `M` is relatively small.

```
A = np.array([C[:,B == i].sum(axis=1) for i in range(M)])
```

Comment: More intuitive and readable than mine, +1.  On a side note, the general approach of "vectorize most of it and loop over the shortest axis" is often a good trade-off between speed and memory usage for things like numpy, matlab, etc.